# list of installed programs without dependencies

Tags: installed-programs

I would like to have a list of the programs that i have installed via USC or terminal but without the their dependencies.
Is it possible? If yes in which mode? I use Ubuntu 13.10
thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed using `sudo apt-get install`, I can show how to get the list of software (and not dependencies).

```
$ cat /var/log/apt/history.log > ~/Desktop/allhistory.log && zcat /var/log/apt/history.log*gz >> ~/Desktop/allhistory.log
```

Will make a simple text file on your Desktop called "allhistory.log".

Among other things you will see, for example:

```
Start-Date: 2014-02-07  20:54:06
Commandline: apt-get install spell
Install: spell:amd64 (1.0-24), ispell:amd64 (3.3.02-6, automatic), ienglish-common:amd64 (3.3.02-6, automatic), iamerican:amd64 (3.3.02-6, automatic)
End-Date: 2014-02-07  20:54:15
```

Look at the second and third lines. What you want is on the second line. What you don't want, dependencies, is on the third line. That is why I like installing/removing/purging with command line.

Now, to make a list, simply run:

```
$ grep ^"Commandline: apt-get install" ~/Desktop/allhistory.log > ~/Desktop/installed_apps.log
```

You'll get a list like this:

```
Commandline: apt-get install --no-install-recommends rox-filer
Commandline: apt-get install spell
Commandline: apt-get install ibritish
Commandline: apt-get install htop
Commandline: apt-get install --no-install-recommends python-pip
Commandline: apt-get install bootchart
```

Obviously, you can clean up the output further.

*Please note that the above does not apply to installing by any other method.*

Answer (score 0):

**Dependencies are nothing but programs**
It is important that you note that dependencies are programs.There is no distinction between programs and dependencies.

Sometimes, what you may consider as dependency, maybe be a complete software which can run on it's own.

So in short,it is not possible.But you can get complete list by using the command

```
dpkg -l
```

If you want the list of only those commands who match a pattern

```
dpkg -l <pattern>
```

will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can list the dependencies of packages with `apt-cache depends <pkg>`

To list some of the packages which do not depend other packages
 use some command line fu:

```
dpkg -l|grep ^ii|while read a b c; \
do apt-cache depends $b|grep -q Depends: || echo $b; done
```